# Filter webpart and consumer web part

Tags: web-part, filter

I have a Customer filter web part tie to a list. and It's working good. and I have a order list web part. The set up is working fine. However, is there a way not to display any order data from the order list web part if there are no selection in the customer filter web part. or if user selects empty.

Comment: I have added the output to show to you it's working as you request in your question!! please check from your side you have configured the provided list as I have mentioned in my answer , also please have a tour in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to know where you can comment and where you can answer Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can disallow displaying any order data from the order list web part if there are no selection in the customer as the following:

- Edit Page > Edit the provided list, in this case, it is the customer.
- Below `Miscellaneous` > uncheck `Send the first row to connected Web Parts when page loads`

[image]

**Output**

[image]

once the item is selected it will filter as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added "Select a Value" to the filter webpart and that worked. Now all 4 other consuming webparts are showing no records. User selects a value from filter and all 4 webparts are showing related values. Thanks everyone for your help.